# html2canvas missing background

Tags: html, background-image, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to generate image from my html page.

When I enter my url
http://prompter.rareapps.org/prompt/prompt-save2.php?p=123

in webpage renderer of html2canvas website (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html) my page is rendered corectly with background.

But when I generate my own canvas, I do not have the background. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        allowTaint: true,
        taintTest: false,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
        window.location.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      }
    });
});
```

What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Looked here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/265 ??

Comment: Thanks. I tried their recommended fix but none work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is fixed in 0.5.0 version (But version 0.5.0 is not yet ready for use).

But have a lot of problems that are being corrected and basic functions that have not yet been implemented.

> Note: html2canvas has no date forecast for 0.5.0 release
>   Note: version 0.4.1 no longer receives updates

The problem is that version 0.5.0 is not ready for use, I reworked your html, see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--// Never put a space/break-line before the DOCTYPE -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Georgia, serif;
            font-size: 4em;
        }
        p {
            padding: 5px 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #main {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: white url('prompt-save-bg.jpg') center top repeat-y;
            max-width: 1263px; /* background-limit*/
            text-align: center;
        }
        #article {
            padding: 5em 2em 0 2em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #article p.info {
            font-size: 0.2em; padding: 40em 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<!CDATA[
    function save(canvas) {/*html2canvas-0.5.0 work with Promise.js*/
        window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#save-image').click(function () {
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                allowTaint: true,
                logging: true,
                taintTest: false,
                onrendered: save /*0.4.1*/
            }).then(save);/*0.5.0-rc*/
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <input value="Generate Image" id="save-image" download="YourFileName.jpg" type="button">

        <div id="article">
            <h2>AUBREY</h2>

            <p>And Aubrey was her name</p>
            <p>A not so very ordinary girl or name</p>
            <p>But who's to blame?</p>
            <p>For a love that wouldn't bloom</p>
            <p>For the hearts that never played in tune</p>
            <p>Like a lovely melody that everyone can sing</p>
            <p>Take away the words that rhyme, it doesn't mean a thing</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>And Aubrey was her name</p>
            <p>We tripped the light and danced together to the moon</p>
            <p>But where was June?</p>
            <p>No, it never came around</p>
            <p>If it did it never made a sound</p>
            <p>Maybe I was absent or was listening too fast</p>
            <p>Catching all the words but then the meaning going past</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>But God I miss the girl</p>
            <p>And I'd go a thousand times around the world just to be</p>
            <p>Closer to her than to me</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>And Aubrey was her name</p>
            <p>I never knew her but I loved her just the same</p>
            <p>I loved her name</p>
            <p>Wish that I had found the way</p>
            <p>And the reasons that would make her stay</p>
            <p>I have learned to lead a life apart from all the rest</p>
            <p>If I can't have the one I want, I'll do without the best</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>But how I miss the girl</p>
            <p>And I'd go a million times around the world just to say</p>
            <p>She had been mine for a day</p>

            <p class="info">
                Prompter generated by RAREAPPS: http://prompter.rareapps.org
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- Worked in `0.4.1` and `0.5.0-rc`.
- Worked in Chrome and Firefox.

Note that I created a function called `save()`, so you can switch between `onrendered` (version 0.4.1) or `then` (version 0.5.0-rc).

I put your background and a `<DIV>` not changed the `<html>` and not the `<body>` because the "html2canvas" is not smart enough to understand the manipulations of `overflow:` in the window.

Note that the `margin:;` in your last paragraph (`<p>`) caused problems both in "html2canvas" as in "Webkit" browser so I used `padding:`

Remember there is more than one way to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the css clean up! when will 0.5.0 be ready? I tried your code but it is getting error `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/rc/build/html2canvas.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: No date for the Release. Download [html2canvas-0.5.0-rc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/rc/build/html2canvas.js) for your server or PC. Prefer to use the 0.5.0 version when it is ready. The version "0.5.0" has been completely rewritten and lack many features, because it is unable to prevent the serious bugs of version "0.4.1" (as the "z-index").

Comment: the background image now works but it only render the visible part. on my test here it renders the whole div including the non visible part [link]http://prompter.rareapps.org/prompt/prompt-save3.php?p=123

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeNascimento, could you explain a little but a bout the edit? I am having a similar issue. Background image (defined by css) on HTML tag is not rendering full height, like it  wasn't repeating.

Comment: @Gabriel The problem can be anything without an example I can not say if it's a bug or your mistake. Create a question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Thanks. I will prepare it. IN the meanwhile, what are the requirements for printing the background images? What was your edit about that made things work? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel for html2canvas if background is a image no needs requirements. Printing is `window.print`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sorry, when printing I meant adding them to the PDF via html2canvas. What are the requirements for backg-images to be shown nicely (as opposite from only showing the visible part)? I was hoping to interpolate that from the edit that you did... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with background images whose background-size attributes are set as cover in 0.4.1 version which is the latest version currently available.

The solution provided from 'fperich' in this page solved my problem:
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/265

According to his solution, just update line 350 in the version 0.4.1 with the following statement:

```
topPos = isNaN(parseInt(bgposition[1], 10)) ? topPos : parseInt(bgposition[1], 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

explicitly set a background style
Eg. if

```
...
 html2canvas(document.body,
        {
            onrendered: function(canvas){
                 var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                var doc = new jsPDF('p','mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
                doc.save($.now()+'.pdf');
        }
```

the pdf has blank (black) background,

now if you add CSS style

```
 body {
         background-color: white;
     }
```

the blank (black) background is corrected