# Printing Div to PNG with html2canvas with background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using html2canvas plugin to print a div to png format. Till now, I can print div to png but background images are missing.

My html2canvas jquery code is

```
 html2canvas($(".comp-card-wrapper"), {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
         // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
         var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         window.open(myImage);
     }
 });
```

Full code is on JsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/j2mpetdz/1/
Please if anyone have any idea, what I am missing, it would be a great help.

Comment: That problem should be fixed in version 0.5.0 and upwards. What version (of html2canvas) are you using?

Comment: Ah, found it myself. you are using version 0.4.1, that should be your problem (let me see if 0.5.0 is available) .

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/265) that will be fixed in html2canvas version 0.5.0. However that version is still not available for use.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22992792/588079) for a possible work-around (which seems compatible with future version 0.5.0RC).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That page is actually explained over here: http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/. Also, as far as I can see they are using a helper jquery plugin: `jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js`