# html2canvas add WaterMark in the center of the pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to convert my HTML page to PDF using html2canvas and jspdf. However, I could not find any resource which mentions adding full screen water mark. Although my html has a background image, when html2canvas converts it to image, it leaves it out. Here is my code

```
function CreatePDFfromHTML() {
    var HTML_Width = $(".html-content").width();
    var HTML_Height = $(".html-content").height();
    var top_left_margin = 5;
    var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
    var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
    var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

    var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;

    html2canvas($(".html-content")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
        for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
            pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
        }
        pdf.save("Result");
        //$(".html-content").hide();
    });
}
```

I have uploaded my screenshot [image] of my html output for reference. I would like to retain the watermark.

Comment: is the "watermark" text your background image? If background image doesn't work, you could just create a new text element (that acts as the watermark) that is absolute or fixed, place it, then take the screen shot and then remove it

Comment: also this may be insightful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569210/html2canvas-missing-background